# How to get nginx to do a redirect to url-encoded query parameter

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-location

I have a requirement to do a proxy call to url delivered via a query parameter as per example:
My nginx proxy is deployed at: `https://myproxy.net`

if the redirect parameter is not url encoded I can do the call with this block:

```
  location /basepath {
        if ( $arg_redirect = '') { 
          return 400 "Missing redirect directive in request"; 
        }
        proxy_pass $arg_redirect;
        proxy_intercept_errors on;
        error_page 301 302 307 = @handle_redirects;
    }
```

the error intercepts and @handle_redirects then take care of othe 30X codes that might pop up at new destination.
This works for a request:
`GET`: `https://myproxy.net/basepath?redirect=https://destination.com/somepath/uuid`

What do I need to do to make it work for:
`GET`: `https://myproxy.net/basepath?redirect=https%3A%2F%2Fdestination.com%2Fsomepath%2Fuuid`

Additionally as part of spec it has to be pure nginx, not additional modules, lua etc.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, `proxy_pass` does normalisation by default, but it only affects `$uri` part. Thus you only need to decode the beginning of the passed string to get it working:

```
  location / {
    if ( $arg_redirect = '') {
      return 400 "Missing redirect directive in request";
    }
    if ( $arg_redirect ~ (.+)%3A%2F%2F(.+) ){ # fix :// between scheme and destination
      set $arg_redirect $1://$2;
    }
    if ( $arg_redirect ~ (.+?)%3A(.*) ){ # fix : between destination and port
      set $arg_redirect $1:$2;
    }
    if ( $arg_redirect ~ (.+?)%2F(.*) ){ # fix / after port, the rest will be decoded by proxy_pass
      set $arg_redirect $1/$2;
    }
    proxy_pass $arg_redirect;
  }
```

With the above I managed to access `http://localhost/?redirect=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A81%2Fsfoo%20something%2Fs`

The solution seems dirty and the only alternative using default modules is `map` (even less cleaner in my opinion). I'd rather split `redirect` argument into pieces: scheme (http or https), destination, port, and uri. With that you would be able to construct full address without rewriting:

```
proxy_pass $arg_scheme://$arg_dest:$arg_port/$arg_uri
```

Comment: Thanks for the example with replacements. The idea with splitting the url into segments is simple as and really should have occurred to me, definitely the cleanest solution so far!

Answer (score 3):

Ok, there is very weird and curious solution

```
server {
  listen 80;
  resolver x.x.x.x;
  location /basepath {
    if ($arg_redirect = '') {
      return 400 "Missing redirect directive in request";
    }
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:80/basepath/$arg_redirect;
  }
  location ~ ^/basepath/(?<proto>\w+):/(?<redir>.+)$ {
    proxy_pass $proto://$redir;
  }
}
```

Nginx does not encode path with variables in proxy_pass and send it as is. So, I make $arg_* part of proxy_pass uri, send request to self and nginx will receive new request which will be decoded.

But because Nginx will clean path and replace `//` to `/` I split protocol part in regexp.

And ... I would never recommend using this solution, but it works :)

Answer (score 0):

try like this and let me know if it works

```
  location /basepath {
        if ( $arg_redirect = '') { 
          return 400 "Missing redirect directive in request"; 
        }

        set_unescape_uri $decodedredirect $arg_redirect;

        proxy_pass $decodedredirect;
        proxy_intercept_errors on;
        error_page 301 302 307 = @handle_redirects;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but `set_????` directives are part of a  [set-misc-nginx-module](https://github.com/openresty/set-misc-nginx-module#readme)

Comment: my apologies I 'v missed the "pure nginx, not additional modules"